# Linux: 'transferring'/mirroring read-only permissions for symlinks (for webserver)

Tags: linux, webserver, file-permissions, pipe, symlink

Please let me explain what I mean by the question:

This is the context: I'm a user on a webserver, where I have `phpicalendar` installed; then, I choose a directory, say `/webroot/mylogin/phpicalendar/mycals` to host my `.ics` calendar text files.

EDIT: *Previously, instead of '`/webroot`', I had used '`/root`' - but I really didn't mean **the** Linux '`/root`' directory - I'm just wanted to use it as a stand in for the real location on the webserver (so it serves just as a common point of reference). Otherwise, what I mean by common point of reference, is simply `/webroot = /media/some/path` ..*

Then, I can enter this directory in the `phpicalendar`'s `config.inc.php`:

```
$configs = array(
 'calendar_path'        => '/webroot/mylogin/phpicalendar/mycals;
 ...
```

Then, `phpicalendar` will run through this directory, grab the .ics files there (say, `mycal.ics` and `mycal2.ics`) and render them - so far, so good.

The thing is, I would now like to add a *second* calendar directory, located at the same webserver, but where I have read-only permissions, say `/webroot/protected/cals`. I know that I have read permissions, because I can do in the shell, say

```
$ less /webroot/protected/cals/maincal.ics
```

and I can read the contents fine.. So now:

- If I enter `/webroot/protected/cals` as a 'calendar_path', `phpicalendar` can read and render the files there (say, '`maincal.ics`', '`maincal2.ics`') without a problem
- However, `phpicalendar` can have only **one** '`calendar_path`', so I can either use the protected calendars, or my customized calendars - but not both
- So, I thought, I could symlink the protected calendars in my customized directory - and get the best of both worlds :)

So, here is a shell snippet of what I would do

```
$ cd /webroot/mylogin/phpicalendar/mycals
$ ls -la 
drwxrwxrwx  2 myself myself 4096 2011-03-03 12:50 .
-rw-r--r--  1 myself myself 1234 2011-01-20 07:32 mycal.ics
-rw-r--r--  1 myself myself 1234 2011-01-20 07:32 mycal2.ics
...

$ ln /webroot/protected/cals/maincal.ics .    # try a hard link first
ln: creating hard link `./maincal.ics' => `/webroot/protected/cals/maincal.ics': Invalid cross-device link'

$ ln -s /webroot/protected/cals/maincal.ics .                  # symlink - works
$ ln -s ../../../protected/cals/maincal.ics relmaincal.ics  # symlink via relative
$ ln -s mycal.ics testcal.ics                               # try a symlink to a local file

$ ls -la                                                    # check contents of dir now
drwxrwxrwx  2 myself myself 4096  .
-rw-r--r--  1 myself myself 1234  mycal.ics
-rw-r--r--  1 myself myself 1234  mycal2.ics
lrwxrwxrwx  1 myself myself   21  testcal.ics -> mycal.ics
lrwxrwxrwx  1 myself myself   56  maincal.ics -> /webroot/protected/cals/maincal.ics
lrwxrwxrwx  1 myself myself   66  relmaincal.ics -> ../../../protected/cals/maincal.ics
```

Ok, so here's what happens:

- `less maincal.ics` works on shell
- `less relmaincal.ics` fails with '`relmaincal.ics: No such file or directory`' (*even if shell autocompletion for the relative path did work during the execution of the symlink command!*)
- When you open `phpicalendar` now, it will render `mycal.ics`, `mycal2.ics` and `testcal.ics` (and they will work)

  - however, maincal.ics and relmaincal.ics will **not** be parsed or displayed

Now - this could be that PHP cannot resolve symlinks; however I speculate that the situation is this:

- When I do `less maincal.ics` - it is `myself` who is user, who has read permission for `/webroot/protected/cals`
- `phpicalendar` (so Apache webserver user) can otherwise also access `/webroot/protected/cals` as read-only, when given 'hardcoded' path
- `phpicalendar` is also capable of reading local symlinks fine

Thus, I suspect, that the problem is: when trying to read the symlinks to protected cals, the user that is visible to the shell during that operation is Apache web user, which then doesn't get permissions to access a *symlink* to the protected/cals location!

The thing now is - I can easily copy the .ics files locally; however they are being changed by someone else, which is why I'd have preferred a symlink.

And my **question** is: can I do some sort of trickery, so that when phpicalendar/Apache tries to access a symlink to protected/cals, it 'thinks' that it is a local file - and otherwise, the contents of the protected/cals file are being 'piped' back to phpicalendar/Apache?? I guess I'm thinking something in terms of:

```
$ mkfifo mypipe
$ ln -s mypipe testpipe.ics
$ cat ./testpipe.ics                                 # in one terminal
$ cat /webroot/protected/cals/maincal.ics > mypipe      # in other terminal
```

... which would otherwise (I think) handle the permissions problem - except that, I don't want to `cat` manually; that would be something that would have to be done in the background, each time an application requests to read `testpipe.ics`:)

Well, thanks in advance for any comments on this - looking forward to hearing some,
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I *really* doubt that the account the web server runs under can read *anything* under `/root`. That directory is usually mode 0700, user root, group root, or something very similar to that - meaning no non-root access is allowed. If you're running the web server as root, file read permissions are the least of your problems...

Your best bet then would be to place the read-only calendar files somewhere publicly available, and symlink to that location from wherever under /root you want to be able to access them.

Comment: Hi @Michael Kjörling, thanks for your comment! My bad, sorry - it's not really **the** `/root` that is the actual folder on the webserver - I just used it as a shorthand for the real common point of reference on the server (_OP now edited, clarification added_)..  Probably should have chosen a different name than the venerable '`/root`' - but I'd rather not change the entire post now :) I have otherwise tried to point out in the post, which permissions work for me - and which don't.. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Just a note - I replaced all previous references to `/root` as `/webroot` now, hope it will make it clearer now...

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking whether the Apache user can view your calendars:

```
you@host $ sudo -i -u <apache-user> -s /bin/bash
apache@host $ less /root/protected/cals/maincal.ics
```

Comment: Hi @nickgrim, thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, '`myself is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`' (and also, '`sudo: you may not specify both the '-i' and '-s' options`'). However, I have also said above: "_If I enter /webroot/protected/cals as a 'calendar_path', phpicalendar can read and render the files_", so some level of access is definitely possible for the Apache user - just not via symlink?!